# Google Chrome fails to install during download process

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, installation

When I go to install Chrome, the  installer pops up and it continues to say it's downlaoding google chrome, but nothing happens. I just uninstalled Chrome  and I figured a reinstall would work perhaps but it doesn't seem to be. I was unable to get help in the chrome forum. I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Something is probably blocking it from connecting to the server. Check your Internet protection software like your firewall/antivirus/router/etc.

Comment: already done that..chorme just don't work for me..  :( ...  still with IE...

Answer (score 2):

Try installing chrome by using the [offline installer](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?standalone=1). This installer has all of the files pre-included, so it doesn't need to do the "downloading chrome" part which is hanging up your computer.

Comment: well thanks a lot! now i have chrome!! but... is there any particular reason why it load pages really really slow.. and some pages don't load at all like "SuperUser"..   this is the reason why i uninstalled it before.. I don't see any reason that i can point it

Comment: Do you have any add-ons in chrome? try disabling all of them and check if same issues occur. Also check this link out: http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113910

Comment: No add-ons at all!

Comment: Not too sure then. Have you checked out the link in the above comment? Do the webpages open fine in other browsers?

Comment: Just finish checking all the options in the link above but unfortunately still no good..  :(

Comment: There’s definitely a problem with your Internet connection (which is why you couldn’t install the other way, and why the update function probably doesn’t work). Check your Internet protection software like blockers and anti-this and that’s to see if something is blocking or slowing your connection down. Also check your router if you have one, and of course, try resetting your modem.

Comment: I have chacked the firewalls (windows and norton) and chrome is allowed there.. is there something else i need to look at?!  what to check in the router?! restart didn't help...

Comment: It’s not Chrome that needs to be allowed to connect, it’s the installer and specifically, Google Update. If you can’t install, it may be that Google Update is the problem. Try erasing the Google Update and Google Chrome directories before installing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this worked, but it did for me.  I was trying to uninstall and re-install Google Chrome because my version was so far out of date I was told to do this.  When I was trying to re-install Chrome, I got an error code of 0x80004002.

This is my workaround:

1. Download a Full Standalone Offline Installer from here:  http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/google-chrome-full-standalone-offline-installer-links
2. Make sure to know where the download file is located on your harddrive.
3. Rebook your computer / laptop in to Safe Mode.  This is usually done by pressing f8 when your computer / laptop is booting up, but you may have to search online on how to enter your computer's Safe Mode.  I don't think it matters, you can either arrow down to Safe Mode or Safe Mode with Networking.  My choice was Safe Mode with Networking.
4. Once you are in Safe Mode, navigate to where your file was downloaded to.
5. Right click on the downloaded file and click on "Open as Administrator."
   You should now see Google Chrome installing.  Once you have installed Google Chrome, close out of all windows and reboot your computer normally.  Once booted up, you should now be able to see Google Chrome on both your desktop and in your pinned area on your task bar.  Double click to open, log into your account and all should be normal again.

I don't know what is causing the issue for me not to be able to download it straight from Google, but at least I have Chrome back now, and hopefully so will you.